# Performance Issue with dynamic SQL query in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I want to create a dynamic SQL query in Excel towards redshift/postgres DBs to enhance a dynamic list of elements with several columns.

Basically I want to be able to copy/type in a list of IDs into excel like the following:

```
Id
------
AAC123
ABB203
AEF678
AEK232
BCE123
BFG304
```

Ideally the SQL query would use a statement like:

```
select * 
from table 
where ID in ('AAC123', 'ABB203', 'AEF678', 'AEK232', 'BCE123', 'BFG304')
```

I managed to create a parameter working with one attribute in Power Query using the following approach https://exceleratorbi.com.au/pass-excel-parameter-power-query/

```
select * 
from table 
where ID = Parameter
```

When I exchange the `= Parameter` with `IN Parameter`, I get the following error:

> Expression Error Token RightParen expected

When I use `IN (Parameter)` instead, I get the same error.

I managed to create a workaround by merging the two tables with an inner join in power query. Unfortunately the table in redshift / postgres has 10M rows plus and refreshing for a list of 25-100 items usually takes 5min plus. The same query without dynamic SQL only takes 15 seconds.

Does anyone have a suggestion what I need to do differently?

Comment: Probably, you are missing some indices on your table?

Comment: What is *Parameter*? A table? A comma separated list? A string?

Comment: @NicoHaase - Unfortunately the only reference to the table I have is a string-column.

Comment: @ParfaitI used the following approach https://exceleratorbi.com.au/pass-excel-parameter-power-query/

Comment: @Andreas adding indices to your database is independent from the way you access the data later in your application.

Comment: @Parfait I used the following approach https://exceleratorbi.com.au/pass-excel-parameter-power-query/

Comment: @NicoHaase I actually try to get the parameterised version working. I wont be able to index the redshift / Psql and they arent indexed as far as i can see.

Answer (score 0):

Load your `ID` table into the query editor and convert it to a list (Transform > Convert To List). I'll assume your table name is `Table1`.

On your query table, select any single `ID` value to filter on. The Query Editor should generate a step with code that looks similar to this:

```
= Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([ID] = "AAC123"))
```

Instead of that, let's replace the selection condition to use `Table1`:

```
= Table.SelectRows(Source, each List.Contains(Table1, [ID]))
```

If you right-click on this step in the Applied Steps section on the right and choose View Native Query, then you should see that the SQL query has a `WHERE` clause just like you have in your post.

This "Native Query" is what gets sent back to the server, so this should improve performance.

---

***Note***: You don't necessarily have to convert to a list first. If you do not convert it to a list, then your filter step will look like this instead (you use the column name):

```
= Table.SelectRows(Source, each List.Contains(Table1[ID], [ID]))
```

---

**Edit:** Since you are using a SQL connection string in you connection, you can include the ID list in a `WHERE` statement in this string:

```
query: = Odbc.Query("dsn=Redshift",
                    "select ID, column_A, column_B
                     from redshift.db.info
                     where ID in (" & Text.Combine(Table1[ID], ",") & ")")
```

(The `Text.Combine` function concatenates the ID column.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Unfortunately it is still very slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Unfortunately it is still very slow.
When I click refresh all data, just connecting to redshift takes at least 2 minutes (Waiting for DSN = Redshift) then it loaded 508 rows but kept going (Running Background Query). 
If I run the same query without parameter / list embedded, refreshing takes 5 seconds with similar amount of IDs to be looked up (25 IDs).

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Actually it never ended refreshing background so I didnt see any results.

Comment: Are there any other steps in the query? Sometimes the Query Editor tries to fold too much into the query it passes back to the database. Can you verify that for just loading the data (and doing nothing else) there is a big difference between loading the list and hardcoding the ID values?

Comment: I have two queries. 1 query called input with the following steps:
= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Input"]}[Content]
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}})

Then i have the actual SQL connection / query:
= Odbc.Query("dsn=Redshift", "select ID, column_A, column_B from redshift.db.info")
= Table.SelectRows(Source, each List.Contains(Input[ID], [ID]))

Is this how you intended it to be set-up?

Comment: If i am setting this up as you suggested without having "Input" as a table but only trying to reference to the ID-list, i get the following error.
Expression.Error: The name 'Table1' wasn't recognized.  even if I used insert table and named it accordingly. Any ideas?

Comment: Bump @Alexis Olson .. could you help here?

Comment: Ah, it looks like you have a custom SQL string in your first step. I think this breaks the query folding. You should either eliminate that custom SQL (and reproduce the column selection in the query editor) or else make it dynamic so that you pass the IDs into a `WHERE` clause there.

Comment: Hey Alexis, I am very sorry but I am struggling with implementation. How do i eliminate that custom SQL? Is it the second part in which I transform ColumnTypes ID into text? or do you suggest just having one query for everything. right now it is two. How to reproduce the column section in the query editor? I assume in the one where i pull data directly, right? And how would i reference to the column in the where clause. How do i tell SQL to use sheet1.column A for an IN selection?

Comment: I'm used to SQL database connections that would look like this: `Source = Sql.Database("ServerName", "DBName"){[Schema="dbo",Item="TableName"]}[Data]` from which you can select columns like this `Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"ColA", "ColB"})`. ODBC might be different, so perhaps you can pass the parameter list into your connection string.